Azure ComputeSku with null costs
I would need your help to understand, why while getting a list of Azure ComputeSku, all of them has its "costs" field set to null (see my screenshot below). It happens with any of my retrieved resource types (virtualMachines, availabilitySets).

Any idea ?
(azure-mgmt-compute 1.41.3)
Thanks in advance

known issue with Azure Analysis Services Pricing Tier scaling table not showing data. But this issue was fixed on May 16, 2024. References:

Known issue - Azure Analysis Services Pricing Tier scaling table doesn't show data. Would suggest you raise a case with MS regarding the same.


The Azure Price Sheet is a bit of a mess.
Download the Microsoft Price Sheet and try to search for the specific VM.
You will see there are tons of version of the same VM based on the region or discount.
Then, based on the columns of the CSV, you now have an idea about how to create an API Call that could give you what you want.

By relying on the AZURE REST API, i do not have any cost in my query result.
The query:
curl --location 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?api-version=2021-07-24' --header 'Authorization:yyy'

The response:
        },
    {
        "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
        "name": "Basic_A0",
        "tier": "Basic",
        "size": "A0",
        "family": "basicAFamily",
        "locations": [
            "australiaeast"
        ],
        "locationInfo": [
            {
                "location": "australiaeast",
                "zones": [
                ],
                "zoneDetails": [
                ]
            }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "MaxResourceVolumeMB",
                "value": "20480"
            },
            {
                "name": "OSVhdSizeMB",
                "value": "1047552"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUs",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "MemoryPreservingMaintenanceSupported",
                "value": "True"
            },
            {
                "name": "HyperVGenerations",
                "value": "V1"
            },
            {
                "name": "MemoryGB",
                "value": "0.75"
            },
            {
                "name": "MaxDataDiskCount",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "CpuArchitectureType",
                "value": "x64"
            },
            {
                "name": "LowPriorityCapable",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "PremiumIO",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "VMDeploymentTypes",
                "value": "IaaS"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUsAvailable",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "ACUs",
                "value": "50"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUsPerCore",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "CombinedTempDiskAndCachedIOPS",
                "value": "200"
            },
            {
                "name": "CombinedTempDiskAndCachedReadBytesPerSecond",
                "value": "13107200"
            },
            {
                "name": "CombinedTempDiskAndCachedWriteBytesPerSecond",
                "value": "13107200"
            },
            {
                "name": "UncachedDiskIOPS",
                "value": "500"
            },
            {
                "name": "UncachedDiskBytesPerSecond",
                "value": "4096000"
            },
            {
                "name": "EphemeralOSDiskSupported",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "EncryptionAtHostSupported",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "CapacityReservationSupported",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "AcceleratedNetworkingEnabled",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "RdmaEnabled",
                "value": "False"
            },
            {
                "name": "MaxNetworkInterfaces",
                "value": "2"
            }
        ],
        "restrictions": [
        ]
    },

